# Visual studio code clang executable

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, clang

I've installed visual studio code on my Ubuntu VM and am using c++.  I keep getting the following error covering the pages tab at the top which is really frustrating:

Please install [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) or check configuration `clang.executable`

I have installed clang using `apt-get install llvm`.  I have installed the c++ support from the packages so I'm not trying to do anything complicated here.

I have googled till I'm now blue in the face, has anyone else come across this and now how to get around this.

Answer (score 5):

It seems `clang` is not installed properly on your **ubuntu**. Install `clang` by:

```
sudo apt-get install clang

clang -v //Now see installed version
```

Now, error should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I too had the same problem and resolved it with the following steps.

1. Installed the llvm plus clang available with the following link
   http://releases.llvm.org/
2. Installed the c/c++ lang adapter (choose this one from the list of extensions in the visual studio code.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mitaki28.vscode-clang

3. Configure the path of the llvm/bin folder installed in step 1 above in the visual studio code 'user settings', with the clang.executable: variable. Please refer to the 'configuration' section explained in the url in step 2.

Comment: @Oliver, hope the answer was helpful to you. If so, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) click on the check mark (✓) beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem, too. And I solve it.
I install llvm from this site:

http://releases.llvm.org/download.html#4.0.0

Then the problem is solved.