# Install Clang in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to configure C++ project located in WSL Ubuntu in my Visual Studio Code. VS Code is asking me to install Clang:

[image]

Why I should do that? How to install Clang?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368731/visual-studio-code-clang-executable